# How to handle issues after generating multiple environment in iOS (Swift)?

Tags: ios, swift, production-environment, ios-targets

I am trying to handle multiple environment in iOS project.
I have followed proper steps of generating "Production" and "Development" Targets.

But, when I try to run Target "Development", it crashes on UI, like,

Problem:
**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key capacityWeightLabel.'**

Solution:

1. For handling this Crash, I have unchecked specific target and checked again.
2. reconnected IBOutlet again to specific control.

Hectic thing is I need to do this for every crash wherever it will appear. How I can handle this situation.?

Please help!

Thanks in advance

Comment: suggestopm instead of crating two different targets you should have set serverURl = "development url" and for production serverURl = "production URLl"
and changed it respectively.  it will cover problem too.

Comment: If we follow standard rule for handling multiple environment, then we have only this way.

We need to generate two different targets.

Please read question carefully. I need solution over multiple Targets.

Answer (score 0):

1- Copy Your Storyboard and other nibs if exist

2- Remove Storyboard and other nibs from Project

3- Drag and drop copied files in to project root folder a popup will appear

4- select the targets you want to share same files

Doing this will allow you to handle these kind of crash issues.

Comment: Yes tried this too. Still it is giving me same error.